# How to enlarge input bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to enlarge input number type form like the text form.
The minimum and maximum number property is crucial.

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  outline: none;
  Font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
Input number:
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5000">

<br><br> Input Form:
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="This is big">
```

Comment: Use font-size: same  as you have done with input text

Answer (score 2):

you need to use this `input[type=number]` to apply code to enlarge input number type

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  outline: none;
  Font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
Input number:
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5000">
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that the up and down button is still small. Is there a way to enlarge them too?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could make that style to be applied to a class, `bigInput` for example:

```
.bigInput {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Then all you have to do is attach the bigInput class to all the input fields that need to have this style:

```
Input number:
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5000" class="bigInput">

<br><br> Input Form:
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="This is big" class="bigInput">
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make the up and down button bigger too?

Comment: @Velo it's not ideal, but you can use `transform: scale(2);` on the number input.